# How to use DelegateDecompiler with ASP.NET OData

Tags: linq-to-entities, odata

*How can ASP.NET OData use computed properties implemented with DelegateDecompiler?*

I have an EF code first model for a legacy database that contains entities with several computed properties.  The computed properties are implemented using DelegateDecompiler.  This works great with regular Linq to Entities queries, you just have to remember to add .Decompile().

I want to expose this EF model using ASP.NET OData query, however if a computed property is included in the filter it will throw InvalidOperationException *"The specified type member 'MyComputedProperty' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."*.  which is expected behavior when .Decompile() is missing.  So it appears the solution is to have .Decompile() added when the OData query is evaluated, but I don't know how to do that.

Sample Code

```
public class MyModel : DbContext
{
    public MyModel() : base("name=MyModel") { }    
    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string someFlag { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    [NotMapped]
    public bool MyComputedProperty
    {
        get { return (someFlag == "Y") ? true : false; }
        set { someFlag = (value) ? "Y" : "N"; }
    }
}

public class MyEntitiesController : ODataController
{
    private MyModel db = new MyModel();

    // GET: odata/MyEntities
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetMyEntities()
    {
        return db.MyEntities;
    }
}
```

With this is sample you can see the InvalidOperationException with this URI  http://localhost/odata/MyEntities?$filter=(MyCustomProperty)